# Apply aspect on non-spring-managed beans

Tags: spring, spring-aop

### Apply aspect on non-spring-managed beans

I have an integration-test which calls a micro-service (abc-service) implemented using drop-wizard framework. My integration test calls a resource end point inside the micro-service. 
This abc-service has dependencies on 2 modules, which I have it in abc-service pom.xml

a.  Aspect-module

b.  Xyz-module --> this module makes http calls to outside service (not in our domain).
This xyz-module has got 15 manager classes and each class has a public static methods, which makes http calls to outside service, I want to calculate processing time for all http calls, i.e I want to apply **@Around advice** on all public static methods which makes http calls in all manager classes.
All classes in xyz-module are non-spring managed beans

[image]

Code in Aspect-module

```
package com.company.abc.operation.aspect
@Aspect
public class AppPerformanceMetricsAspect {
    //@Around("execution(* com.company.product.abc.manager..*(..))")     -- did'nt work
    //@Around("execution(* com.company.product.abc.manager.*.*(..))")    -- did'nt work
    //@Pointcut("execution(* com.company.product.abc.manager.StoreDocumentManager.helloWorld(..))")  -- did'nt work
   // @Pointcut("within(om.company.product.abc.manager.*)")   -- did'nt work
    @Around("execution(* com.company.product.abc.manager.StoreDocumentManager.helloWorld())")   //-- did'nt work
    public Object getVaultManagerPerformanceMetrics(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n  ########### I am here aaaaaaaaaaaa");
        String packageName = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
        String methodName = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object output = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Exiting method [" + packageName + "." + methodName + "]; exec time (ms): " + elapsedTime);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Code in micro-service (a configuration class in abc-microservice), which loads aspect on starting up micro-service, I see aspect (**AppPerformanceMetricsAspect**) getting registered to the spring container, captured logs on start of the abc-service (micro-service)

```
INFO  [2018-09-28 13:54:28,809] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14b99c84: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,springConfiguration,signingStrategyFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,supportCompensatingOperationsAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration,loadTimeWeaver,org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.SpringConfiguredConfiguration,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect, AppPerformanceMetricsAspect]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Few stack over articles suggested remove @EnableAspectJAutoProxy and use @EnableLoadTimeWeaving.
For EnableLoadTimeWeaving to work, I made use of

VM options : -javaagent:C:/dev/selenium/aspectj-weaver.jar -javaagent:C:/dev/selenium/spring-instrument-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED) – didn’t work
@EnableSpringConfigured – didn’t work
//@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) – this didn’t work
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.company.abc.operation.aspect")
// path to the package where my aspect is defined AppPerformanceMetricsAspect
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {
@Bean
    public VaultManagerPerformanceMetricsAspect vaultManagerPerformanceMetricsAspect() {
        return new VaultManagerPerformanceMetricsAspect();
    } // even this didn’t work
}
```

==============================================================================
**Attempt 1** : I am trying to integrate your solution into my project, its not working. 
When I start my micro-service with VM options as

-javaagent:C:/dev/selenium/aspectj-weaver.jar -javaagent:C:/dev/selenium/spring-instrument-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar

This is what I see in logs
I see all classes within package (com.abc.test.xyz.manager) are getting weaved

```
`[AppClassLoader@561279c8] debug weaving 'com.abc.test.xyz.manager.TestManager'
[AppClassLoader@561279c8] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void'com.abc.test.xyz.manager.TestManager.execute())' in Type ''com.abc.test.xyz.manager.TestManager ' (TestManager.java:23) advised by around advice from 'com.test.compensating.operation.aspect.PerformanceMetricsAspect' (PerformanceMetricsAspect.java)'
```

but when I try to run my test

```
'ERROR [2018-11-30 19:15:14,435] com.abc.dropwizard.exceptionmappers.GenericExceptionMapper: Unhandled Service Error
! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test.compensating.operation.aspect.PerformanceMetricsAspect.aspectOf()Lcom/test/compensating/operation/aspect/PerformanceMetricsAspect;`
```

Iam running my micro service using java 1.7
Made sure my micro-service project (similar to tasklist-service project which I created in github in my previous post) has this entry in pom.xml    `

```
<build>
…
…
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.14.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>ajc</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   </plugin>
</build>`
```

My aspect is defined in a different module i.e
abc-compensating-operations module and this is similar to  calculate-metrics project which I created in github in my previous post
abc-compensating-operations module has below dependencies in pom.xml

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>`
```

Comment: Your basic course of action to use AspectJ LTW instead of Spring AOP is correct if you want to weave non-Spring stuff. Probably your configuration is incorrect in some detail, but maybe your aspect or your Maven build could also have a problem. I need to see the full picture in order to say for sure. Would you please prepare an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me and post it on GitHub so I can build a sample project reproducing the problem by myself and find your what is wrong?

Comment: @kriegaex added project here,  https://github.com/sharathk0525/loadtime-aop-dropwizard/tree/sharathk0525-patch-1  . I mimicked (taskilist-service) project and made sure iam using the same version of jars  which I have been using in my real-project at work.      Also tried using VM options as   -javaagent:C:/dev/aspect-jars/aspectj-weaver.jar -javaagent:C:/dev/aspect-jars/spring-instrument-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @kriegaex, inorder to set up your work space, you need to import 3 projects  a. tasklist  b. service-provider c. calculate-metrics to your workspace from  https://github.com/sharathk0525/loadtime-aop-dropwizard/tree/sharathk0525-patch-1

Comment: Hey Sharath, how about providing feedback and maybe accepting and upvoting my answer? I took quite some time to fix your GitHub project and answer your problem.

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks for your help on this issue. It worked for me.  The code what you shared on  github is really helpful. Only thing what I noticed is -- it works on JDK 1.7 not 1.8. I accept your answer I upvoted it.

Comment: This is not true. I used Java 8 during development. Just now I even explicitly added [source and target level 8](https://github.com/kriegaex/loadtime-aop-dropwizard/commit/12602f9d127353afb13f443f8490cb8dd7b53db4) for Maven Compiler plugin in in my fork of your project explicitly for all three modules, and it still works. Your problem is not the Java version but some kind of configuration in your own environment.

Comment: I saw your deleted answer (which was actually a follow-up question). If you deleted it, I hope it means you solved your problem - probably the aspect JAR was missing on the classpath - by yourself. Besides, you said you accepted and upvoted my answer. But that is not true. Maybe you forgot that, please do it now.

Comment: Accepted your answer and upvoted it. I updated the question would read it again from attempt 1============

Comment: Can you confirm that my fork of your sample repo works? Why didn't you just use my solution? If you tried, maybe you forgot something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected your GitHub repo. First I unpacked and removed all ZIP files (very ugly to commit them, especially including *target* directory contents) and added a parent POM in order to be able to properly build the whole project. Then I noticed that there were several things wrong:

If you want to use your aspect module via LTW, you need to provide a properly configured *aop.xml* file according to the [AspectJ LTW documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html), e.g. like this:

```xml
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="com.test.compensating.operation.aspect.PerformanceMetricsAspect"/>
  </aspects>

  <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="com.test..*"/>
  </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Furthermore, your pointcut was wrong:

```java
@Around("execution(* com.test.manager.performOperation())")
```

Instead, it should be (please note the `..` notation):

```java
@Around("execution(* com.test.manager..performOperation())")
```

Now you can run your main class from the IDE and see the following log output during start-up:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.1 built on Friday Apr 20, 2018 at 16:47:33 GMT
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration /C:/Users/alexa/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_Spring_ApplyOnNonSpring/calculate-metrics/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect com.test.compensating.operation.aspect.PerformanceMetricsAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
(...)
INFO  [2018-11-05 11:23:03,317] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started application@7249dadf{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO  [2018-11-05 11:23:03,321] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started admin@4362d7df{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO  [2018-11-05 11:23:03,322] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @4168ms
```

If you access http://localhost:8080/task-list, you also see that the aspect works:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.test.manager.AdditionManager.performOperation())' in Type 'com.test.manager.AdditionManager' (AdditionManager.java:16) advised by around advice from 'com.test.compensating.operation.aspect.PerformanceMetricsAspect' (PerformanceMetricsAspect.java)

  ########### I am here aaaaaaaaaaaa
Adding 2 numbers 1 2 = 12
Exiting method [com.test.manager.AdditionManager.performOperation]; exec time (ms): 0
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [05/Nov/2018:11:23:12 +0000] "GET /task-list HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36" 251
```

Besides, your uber JAR also was configured incorrectly, i.e. the application threw an error when started from the uber JAR. Never having used Dropwizard before, I googled and then fixed it [like this](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.4/docs/getting-started.html#building-fat-jars).

I created a [forked repo branch](https://github.com/kriegaex/loadtime-aop-dropwizard/tree/kriegaex-fix-project) and a [pull request](https://github.com/sharathk0525/loadtime-aop-dropwizard/pull/2) for you. Enjoy!